# Fading in element with the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am having troubles with this code. It's supposed to do this:

1. Start the function with clicking on an element with class "portfolioImage".
2. Fade out all the elements with class "image".
3. Fade in element with class "image" and id of the "portfolioImage" (lets say the id of portfolioImage is 3, so fade in the elements that has class image and id 3).
4. Fade out an element with id "portfolioHolder" and fade in another element with class "details".

Parenting:
   #portfolioHolder (visible at the start of the function)
      .portfolioImage
   #details (invisible at the start of the function)
      .image

My Code:

```
$(function(){
$("div.portfolioImage").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).id;
    window.print($(this).id);
    $("div#portfolioHolder").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $("div#details").fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $("div.image").each.fadeOut('slow', function(){/*complete*/});
    $("div.image#"+id.toString()).fadeIn('slow', function(){/*complete*/});
});
```

});

-- David

Comment: If I am not getting it wrong, you cannot have two elements with same id.

Comment: In jQuery you get attributes by like  $(this).attr('id'), not $(this).id

Comment: You can just use `this.id` to get element id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs should be unique! But you can use data-id or any data-X instead...

Instead of:

```
<div class="portfolioImage" id="3">...</div>
<div class="image" id="3">...</div>
```

use:

```
<div class="portfolioImage" id="image3">...</div>
<div class="image" data-id="image3">...</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('.portfolioImage').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   $('.image').fadeOut('slow');
   $('.image[data-id='+id+']').fadeIn('slow');
   $('#portfolioHolder').fadeOut('slow');
   $('.details').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

should be right

Comment: Thanks for answering! It's almost perfect, the only thing is that the old .image elements don't fade out.

Comment: Now I know why is that, it's because by fading in the parent element of the .image elements, you fade all of them in too. Is there any way to only fade in the parent element?

Comment: whats the parentElement? Maybe $('.image[data-id='+id+']').fadeIn('slow');  $('.image[data-id='+id+'] .image').fadeOut('slow');

Comment: easier would first calling fadeIn's, then the fadeOut's. Maybe Like your Code, if animation is completed..

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code.

1. You can retreive the id using `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`
2. `$("div.image").each.fadeOut` will throw an error because `each` is a method and you are trying to use it as a property and calling `fadeOut` method on it. You don't have to use `each` here because `$("div.image").fadeOut()` will take care of running `fadeOut` on all the selected elements.

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $("div.portfolioImage").click(function(){
      var id = this.id;

      $("div#portfolioHolder").fadeOut('slow', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
      $("div#details").fadeIn('slow', function() {
          // Animation complete.
      });
      $("div.image").fadeOut('slow', function(){/*complete*/});
      $("div.image#"+id).fadeIn('slow', function(){/*complete*/});
  });
});
```